# chess sliding pieces bitboards

Tags: c, 64-bit, bit-manipulation, chess, bitmask

I understood non-sliding pieces quite easily but I've been having some trouble with the sliding pieces.

I currently have 64 bitboards (1 for each square, not saved in a array as well as 8 bitboards for masked rows, 8 bitboards for cleared rows, 8 bitboards for masked columns, and 8 bitboards for cleared columns, as well as, of course, a bitboard for each type of piece.

In generating legal moves for the bishop and rook I hear you are suppose to get the first occupied square on the column/row.

My questions are:

- how do you know where the rook is to and it together with the appropriate mask.
- how exactly do you get the first occupied square in the diagonal as well for the Bishop.
- if you know of any other common bitboards which will help me in my tasks at a latter point, please let me know of them.

Currently I have it going with no branches and would like to keep the amount of branches I use down but I feel some will be needed here and am curious about the most efficient way to go about solving this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia entries on [Board representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Board_representation_%28chess%29) and [Bitboard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitboard) provide good explanation on the topic.

Moreover, they contain a bunch of interesting links pointing to valuable references.

I particularly advise you to study [Crafty](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crafty)'s source code. It was written by a well known authority: Dr.[Robert Hyatt](http://www.cis.uab.edu/info/faculty/hyatt/hyatt.html).